# How to run aliases commands in inside the vim editor?

Tags: bash, vim, alias

In .bashrc file
set alias

```
alias l='ls -l'
```

Inside Vim:

```
:! l
[No write since last change]
/bin/bash: l: command not found

shell returned 127
```

Comment: Answered over on [vi.se]: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11167/why-do-exclamation-shell-commands-in-gvim-show-error-syntax-error-near-unexp https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/bash-not-recognizing-aliases-when-run-from-vim

Comment: A case for https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 11):

Aliases are not inherited, so the shell that Vim starts would not inherit the aliases that are available in the shell that you started the editor from.

The `~/.bashrc` file is only read for interactive shell sessions, and the shell that you start from Vim is not interactive.  Furthermore, the `bash` shell does not expand aliases in non-interactive shells by default.

To run a command called `l` from within Vim, that command has to be available as an external command (e.g. a script somewhere in your `$PATH`), *or* you may use a separate `$BASH_ENV` file (a file that is read before running anything in a non-interactive shell) to set up a shell environment suitable for what you want to do.

To use the `$BASH_ENV` "trick", make sure that your `~/.vimrc` file (or equivalent) sets this environment variable to the pathname of a file that contains the necessary setup code:

```
let $BASH_ENV = "~/.vim_bash_env"
```

Then create `~/.vim_bash_env` to say

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
source ~/.bashrc
```

This would enable the expansions of aliases even though the shell session is non-interactive, and then it would read your `~/.bashrc` file where presumably your aliases are defined.

You may then use your aliases with Vim's `!` command.

Note that the file that `$BASH_ENV` points to would be read and executed for *any* command that you execute with `!` in Vim, and that if your `~/.bashrc` file does other things like start `tmux` or other services, then this would happen for any command that you start from Vim too.  It would therefore be prudent to factor out the alias and/or shell function definitions into a new `~/.bash_aliases` file that you source from *both* `~/.vim_bash_env` and `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I believe aliases and shell function definitions may also exist in `~/.alias`.